# android gravity right cursor shows left of the input text EditText

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Kotlin. I have used gravity right so that input number start from right. But EditText cursor keep stay always left of the input text in EditText. I want to keep gravity right & text right to left.Here is the image 
[image]

Here is my EditText xml code..

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_amount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"       
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"           
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="right|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLength="6" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Please help me so that input text start from left to right & cursor show always right.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this one
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
EditText text = new EditText(context);
    text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String  text1 = text.getText().toString();
            text.setText(text1);
            text.setSelection(text1.length());
        }
    });
```

it will be work;

hope to help you

Comment: App is getting crashed, is there any other way

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this to your edittext:
`android:textDirection="rtl"`